# I assigned a long variable but the error message claims it´s an int

Tags: c, variables, integer, long-integer, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    long card;
    do
    {
        card = get_long("Type crdit card number\n");
    }
    while (card < 0);
    long c = card;
    int i = 1;
    for (long o = 10; c >= 10;o *= 10, i++)
    {
        c = c / 10;
    }
    for (int h = 0, o = 10; h < i; h++, o *= 10)
    {
        c = card;
        c = c % o;
        printf("%ld\n", c);
        printf("%ld\n", o);
    }
}
```

I'm working on an assignment that requires that I work with credit cards numbers, so I've been using long variables, such as the 'o' on line 14, but I keep getting "format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'int'" as an error message when I try to print it, and I have no clue as to why. I'm quite new to programming so this might be just a beginner's mistake, so any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the loop

```
for (int h = 0, o = 10; h < i; h++, o *= 10)
{
    c = card;
    c = c % o;
    printf("%ld\n", c);
    printf("%ld\n", o);
}
```

`o` is declared as `int`. You should also declare it as `long`.

```
for (long h = 0, o = 10; h < i; h++, o *= 10) /* use long instead of int */
{
    c = card;
    c = c % o;
    printf("%ld\n", c);
    printf("%ld\n", o);
}
```

Comment: tahnk you very much, but, is there a way to declare two variables of different types on the same for loop ?